# Algorithms/Data structures for collapsing overlapping events on a timeline

Tags: algorithm, timeline

I'm looking for an algorithm to do the following. I have a timeline of events which span periods of time which can overlap. I'd like to collapse these events into a single timeline non-overlapping periods of time, each defined by the presence of one or more events.

While conceptually simple, it can be a little messy to catch all the possible cases and split up the timeline appropriately.

To illustrate (here the horizontal axis is time):

```
Event A   -----
Event B      ----
```

becomes

```
Event A   ---
Event A+B    --
Event B        --
```

Another Example:

```
A    -----------
B       ---
C            --
```

Becomes:

```
A    ---
A+B     ---
A          --
A+C          --
A              -
```

Are there any standard algorithms/data structures for doing this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the start and end times of every event in an array, and sort them in non-decreasing order of time (if a "start" and an "end" happen and the same time, break ties by placing the "end" first).

We'll do a [sweep line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) algorithm.

Traverse the sorted array, while maintaining a set of "active" events: whenever you see a start/end time, respectively add or drop the corresponding event from the set, and add (if the active set is non-empty) an event to your solution.

The resulting set of events is disjoint, and can be labelled as needed.

Comment: By non-decreasing you mean... increasing?

Comment: @NickMitchinson Consider `[1,2,2,3]` - it may or may not be considered increasing (depending on definitions), but it is definitely non-decreasing.

Comment: To make `"if appropriate"` a little more clear - you must only process each time once for equal start/end times. Also, your phrasing is somewhat ambiguous, rather - `"... whenever you see a start or end time, respectively add or drop ..."`.

Comment: @Dukeling that is what I was asking, and did not mean to come off as sarcastic or confrontational. I realize now that it may have come off that way.

Comment: @Dukeling: thanks, made an edit, although my current wording is still imprecise in the "add an event to your solution" part.

Comment: My pre-edited comment said to place "end" first, but this actually doesn't really matter, but you do need to make sure that when they are equal, you don't add an event to your solution in both cases.